# How can I animate the color change of Floating Action Button continuously

Tags: android, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I want to change the color of floating action button continuously, like infinite loop. I've tried `ValueAnimator` but that is not working. It only execute once. I've add this in `onCreate` method .

here is my code:

```
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), R.color.colorAccent, R.color.colorPrimary);
    colorAnimation.setDuration(250); // milliseconds
    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
            fab.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            System.out.println("Working");
        }

    });
    colorAnimation.start();
```